# Building an object through two associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Is it possible to build an object through two `has_many` associations? For example:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def create
  @post = current_account.posts.build(params[:post])
  @post.author = current_user # I want to compact this line into the previous one
end
```

I did some research and found this:

```
@article = current_account.posts.build(params[:post], user_id: current_user.id)
```

However, that did not work. In console, I kept getting `user_id: nil` whenever I built a new object.

Another potential solution I could not implement:

```
@post = current_account.post_with_user(current_user).build(params[:post])
```

But every implementation of `post_with_user` I wrote failed.

My associations are as follows:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id', inverse_of: :discussions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :discussions, inverse_of: :author
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :account
  has_many :discussions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing your code shows you trying to do, you should be able to do.  It should look something like this:

```
@article = current_account.posts.build(params[:post])
```

Because you're building off of the list of the current account's posts, you don't have to pass the current account's ID.  (I'm not sure if your current_user is the same as your current_account, you may wish to clarify this).

To compact your post creation into one line, you can do one of two things.

1. Turn the relationship between a user/author and a post into a two-way relationship.  Check out the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html where an order belongs_to a customer, and a customer has_many orders.  You can customize the name of the relationship so that a post has an "author" instead of a user, by calling it "author" but then using the class_name parameter which I assume would take the value :user.
2. Add a after-create hook to the Post class, and set the author value to the same as the current user.  I can't fill in much more detail about this without knowing anything about your user subsystem.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I added my models to clarify what I meant. I already setup an author association. My accounts are scoped by subdomain, and each account has many users. I want to ensure that when a post is created, it's scoped to the current account, fetched via-subdomain, and it's also associated with the user.

Comment: So the current_account and the current_user are different objects, and you do have the relationship between a post and a author two_way.  So you can do the after-create hook suggestion, or you can pass the current_user in as the :author value, merged with the params as your other respondent showed but with a different hash key value:  @article = current_account.posts.build(params[:post].merge({:author => current_user})).  The important thing here is that the build call takes a hash where the keys of the hash are association names or field names of the object being built.

Answer (score 1):

The `params` variable is just a hash, so something along these lines should work to give you a one liner:

```
@post = current_account.posts.build params[:post].merge({ :user_id => current_user.id })
```

Comment: good suggestion, but I do include `use_id` in my accessible attributes, so unfortunately that will raise a `MassAssignment::Security` error! Helpful nevertheless! +1